# Forces, circular motion, waves

Tags: forces

I imagine there is a force acting on the ocean parallel to the surface and of course the force of gravity acting perpendicular and force normal to the surface. I have two questions regarding ocean waves.

What is the mathematical explanation of how ocean waves rise in regards to these forces prescribed above?

What is the physical explanation for the maintaining of the integrity of the arc of an ocean wave until it finally crashes?

** new thought: Is it the simultaneous interaction between the water being pulled and pushed that causes this?

Comment: https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/wavesinocean.html